# How can I run multiple node.js scripts from a main node.js scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am totally new to node.js .I have two node.js script that I want to run . I know I can run them separately but I want to create a node.js script that runs both the scripts .What should be the code of the main node.js script?

Comment: You can just make the two scripts be modules that each export one master function.  You `require()` them in and execute that one master function on each.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you need to do is to use the node.js module format, and export the module definition for each of your node.js scripts, like:

```
//module1.js
var colors = require('colors');

function module1() {
  console.log('module1 started doing its job!'.red);

  setInterval(function () {
    console.log(('module1 timer:' + new Date().getTime()).red);
  }, 2000);
}

module.exports = module1;
```

and

```
//module2.js
var colors = require('colors');

function module2() {
  console.log('module2 started doing its job!'.blue);

  setTimeout(function () {

    setInterval(function () {
      console.log(('module2 timer:' + new Date().getTime()).blue);
    }, 2000);

  }, 1000);
}

module.exports = module2;
```

The `setTimeout` and `setInterval` in the code are being used just to show you that both are working concurrently. The first module once it gets called, starts logging something in the console every 2 second, and the other module first waits for one second and then starts doing the same every 2 second.

I have also used [npm colors package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors) to allow each module print its outputs with its specific color(to be able to do it first run `npm install colors` in the command). In this example `module1` prints `red` logs and `module2` prints its logs in `blue`. All just to show you that how you could easily have concurrency in JavaScript and `Node.js`.

At the end to run these two modules from a main `Node.js` script, which here is named `index.js`, you could easily do:

```
//index.js
var module1 = require('./module1'),
  module2 = require('./module2');

module1();
module2();
```

and execute it like:

```
node ./index.js
```

Then you would have an output like:

[image]

Comment: if a module block then all block ?

Comment: @Hacketo The quick answer is yes. But the point is NodeJS doesn't provide a multi-threaded solution and the main concurrency model in NodeJS and JavaScript is based on the [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop). setTimeout and setInterval both use this event loop feature just to prevent us from blocking on IO. To be more specific you could use Web Workers to implement a solution similar to a multi-threading approach but workers are still all from within a single Node process.

Comment: @Hacketo There are a bunch of well known practices in the world of JavaScript and NodeJS which are considered bad to prevent us from blocking on IO. In the NodeJS world the famous synchronous fs.readFile is one of them and in browser synchronous XHR requests is the other bad practice which block the whole thread.

Comment: @Hacketo if interested in the WebWorker solution, check out the [webworker-threads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `child_process.spawn` to start up each of node.js scripts in one. Alternatively, `child_process.fork` might suit your need too.

[Child Process Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)