# Running independent scripts at once with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have several independent .js files that I want to run together/at once, is that possible/is there any way to do that efficiently? Each script contains a block of code, not only a single function.

Comment: Can you use modules?

Comment: @CertainPerformance doesn't that require calling functions inside main.js? I'm sorry I'm new to nodejs, this is all I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560968/how-can-i-run-multiple-node-js-scripts-from-a-main-node-js-scripts

Comment: Yeah, just like that - just have your main call and execute all your independent script files

Comment: That worked, thank you!